# Disable Draggable Element Outside The Body

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc

When I dragging a element. it goes outside of the body. How can I disable or make draggable inside the body.

```
    <div id="drag" style="background-color:red;">
        <fieldset>
            <h2 class="fs-title">Login</h2>
            <h3 class="fs-subtitle"></h3>

            <input name="UserName" type="text" placeholder="Username">
            <input name="Password" type="Password" placeholder="Password">
            <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="New User" />

            <input type="submit" name="next" class="nexts action-login" value="Log in" />
        </fieldset>

    </div>
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#drag").draggable();
    });
</script>

    @section Scripts {
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
    }
```

https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=D9BCBB2A676D6E13!5568&authkey=!AOCTi6Ss3joIqzA&v=3&ithint=photo%2cJPG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `containment` to constraint draggable :

```
$("#drag").draggable({ containment: "parent" });
```

For more details :

**http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-containment**

OR if u want that draggable donot go outside body then :

```
 $("#drag").draggable({ containment: "body" });
```

Comment: When i am dragging an element ,its okay for left and right...but it goes far about windows height

Comment: @SirushtiDed draggable should be within ur body but if ur problem persists then follow this link http://forums.greensock.com/topic/9605-draggable-on-body-element/  it will work for u..

Answer (score 1):

this will disallow the `#drag` to get out of the body:

```
$("#drag").draggable({containment:'body'});
```